# implementing conway game of life

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm

```
function seed() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

function same([x, y], [j, k]) {
    return x === j && y === k;
}

// The game state to search for `cell` is passed as the `this` value of the function. 
function contains(cell) {
    return this.some(c => same(c, cell));
}

const sum = ([x, y], [j, k]) => [x + j, y + k];

const getNeighborsOf = ([x, y]) => {
    const neighborDeltas = [
        [-1, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [-1, 0], /* */ , [1, 0],
        [-1, -1],
        [0, -1],
        [1, -1]
    ];
    return neighborDeltas.map((d) => sum(d, [x, y]));
}

const livingNeighbors = getLivingNeighbors(cell, state);

return (
    livingNeighbors.length === 3 ||
    contains.call(state, cell) && livingNeighbors.length === 2);
}

const corners = (state = []) => {
    const xs = state.map(([x, _]) => x);
    const ys = state.map(([_, y]) => y);
    return {
        topRight: [Math.max(...xs), Math.max(...ys)],
        bottomLeft: [Math.min(...xs), Math.min(...ys)]
    };
};


const calculateNext = (state) => {
    const { bottomLeft, topRight } = corners(state);
    let result = [];
    for (let y = topRight[1] + 1; y >= bottomLeft[1] - 1; y--) {
        for (let x = bottomLeft[0] - 1; x <= topRight[0] + 1; x++) {
            result = result.concat(isAlive([x, y], state) ? [
                [x, y]
            ] : []);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

const printCell = (cell, state) => {
    return contains.call(state, cell) ? 'x' : '_';
};

const printCells = (state) => {
    const { bottomLeft, topRight } = corners(state);
    for (let y = topRight[1]; y >= bottomLeft[1]; y--) {
        let row = [];
        for (let x = bottomLeft[0]; x <= topRight[0]; x++) {
            row.push(printCell([x, y], state));
        }
        console.log(row.join(''));
    }
};

exports.seed = seed;
exports.same = same;
exports.contains = contains;
exports.sum = sum;
exports.getNeighborsOf = getNeighborsOf;
exports.getLivingNeighbors = getLivingNeighbors;
exports.isAlive = isAlive;
exports.corners = corners;
exports.calculateNext = calculateNext;
exports.printCell = printCell;
exports.printCells = printCells;
```

I am getting an error.

> In this project you will build a simple two dimensional simulation of living cells, known as Conway’s Game of Life. In the process you will learn all about JavaScript functions, including what you can do with them and their many features.

Comment: You are welcome to ask questions about homework here, but you must be specific. Please provide more detail, like what error you get, what you think might be causing the error, and what you have tried to fix it.  See these guidelines: [Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/943435)

Comment: Tried any debugging yet? What have you found out so far?

Comment: atleast tell us what error you're getting so we know what to look for

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting?